# VueJS/Vuetify custom styles are not being included in production builds

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

**Edit** I fixed the issue by moving the custom css to its own file inside the assets directory and then importing it after the vuetify css in `main.js`. But is there a way to make it work while keeping the css in the `.vue` files?

I am having an issue with building the production version for my Vue app. During dev, i added some scoped, but mostly global css styles that overrides some of the styles of Vuetify, and it all works great during development, but when i try to build and serve for production, the styles are missing.

Example custom style in the `vue` files

```
.v-card__title{
padding: 8px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-size: initial
}
```

My `vue-cli` setup is basically the same as the the default setup when creating a project with `vue-cli`. The only thing i changed was adding a `proxyTable` object during dev.

I tried setting `NODE_ENV="production"` as an envar, removing the `proxyTable` option, but the built version does not include the dev styles.

My production express server is simply serving the build files using:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile('index.html', {root: publicRoot})
});
```

All the functionatlity of the app works fine, just not my styles. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: have you checked if the styles are actually there but are overwritten by the default? I'd think the build might have another "order" to process the stylesheet files.

Comment: @FrankProvost I can see in the build output that the app.somerandom.css is being build, but it is definitely being overridden by the default vuetify styles.

Comment: Where did you define your global styles? Are you scoped styles working?

Comment: Most of my styles are defined in the vue files themselves. to define global, i am not including the `scoped` param in the style tag. I also tried moving all the global styles out of the vue files, and into a css file in assets, and then importing that in main on top of vuetify.min.css. still the same result

Comment: @FrankProvost Correction, i imported my css file below the vuetify.min.css file, and that order seems to fix the issue... but seems hacky that it it cannot override the styles from the vue files itself...